# how meteorJs handle synchronisation of big sets of data?

Tags: meteor

I'd like to know how meteorJs manage the synchronization of big sets of data.

Lets say we bind the results of find query which return return a variable number between 1000 to 10.000 records with 10 fields each, the find query change all the time depending on the users input and each time give new sets of data ! its a bit extreme but it'll help me to understand.

so how meteor sync this ? is it gonna send them all at once (waiting for data to load => latency in the reactivity of the UI => not so good for the user experience) ? or divide them to chunks and send them, and there the user would see information appears gradually ?

if we can control the flow, can you give direction please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each document is sent in its own DDP message. DDP is Meteor's data protocol, currently riding atop sockjs as a transport layer. When the user first opens a Meteor web page, the server sends them all the data they are subscribed to.

Later, as the data is updated, the Meteor server calculates exactly which information that the client knows about has changed, and only sends updates for the parts that are different.

To control latency in your application, it is important to remove autopublish from your project, and to carefully decide on the cursors you will publish to clients so that each client needs to receive only the information the web browser is likely to need to display in the next minute or so.

As all of this is happening, the client re-renders every set of changes as soon as it is received.  If you want to control this, you can set a session variable that controls rendering, which you can set from each subsciption's onComplete callback.